# ¿cómo debo llamar al store para que se cumpla un if?

Tags: sql

Tengo un store procedure que le meto 3 if:

```
IF @Tipo = '1'
 begin

 END
IF @Tipo = '2'
 begin

 END
IF @Tipo = '3'
 begin

 END
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta me parece esta relacionada a como crear el [Stored Procedure](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedimiento_almacenado), debes recibir una variable Tipo, entonces sería:

```
Create PROCEDURE  miProcedimiento

@Tipo VARCHAR(10)

AS

IF @Tipo = '1'
 BEGIN
 -- Realiza operacion.
 END

IF @Tipo = '2'
 BEGIN
 -- Realiza operacion.    
 END

IF @Tipo = '3'
 BEGIN
 -- Realiza operacion.    
 END
```

Aquí tienes la documentación oficial de Microsoft para **[como Crear un Stored Procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-us/library/ms345415.aspx)** (Procedimiento Almacenado).

Answer (score 0):

**Procedimiento Almacenado**

```
Create Proc PruebaIf
@Tipo int
AS


if @Tipo = 1
 begin
 PRINT 'Tipo 1'
 END


IF @Tipo = 2
 begin
  PRINT 'Tipo 2'
 END


IF @Tipo = 3
 begin
  PRINT 'Tipo 3'
 END
```

**Ejecución del SP**

```
EXEC PruebaIf 1
EXEC PruebaIf 2
EXEC PruebaIf 3
```

Comment: Lo hice con tipo INT en vez de Char porque me parece mas correcto y ágil